# order topology and discrete topology

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

I have this homework question. Consider the set $X = \{1,2,3\}$.

> $(a)$ With the natural order on $X$, find the basis for its order topology,
>
> $(b)$ Show that the order topology on $X$ equals its discrete topology.

I  suppose  the  natural  order  to  be $1<2<3$, so  that $1$ the is the least  element  and  $3$  is the largest element, then
$B=\{[1,3),(1,3),(1,3]\}$ is   the  basis for the  order topology on $X$.

For part $(b)$, I would like to write $B=\bigg\{\{1,2\},\{2\},\{2,3\}\bigg\}$ but I see  it  will not  satisfy.
I  need help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope we are working with the same definition of [order topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology).

According to this defintion, the base contains all intervals $(a,b)$, $(a,\infty)$, $(-\infty,b)$. (Of course, the base for a topological space is not determinecd uniquely, but this is the one from definition.) Since this set has largest and smallest element, you can rewrite them as (a,b), (a,3], [1,b).

Since, [1,2)={1}, (1,3)={2}, (2,3]={3}, the base contains all singletons and thus the space is discrete.